# How to persist data when edit fails in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, jqgrid-inlinenav

I perform jqgrid edit via formatter actions. And when the edit validations fails in server and I display the errors to user, I want to remain in the edit mode and save the user entered data. 
Is it possible. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `restoreAfterError: false` option of inline editing. I recommend you to set the option by changing defaults of inline editing:

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
    restoreAfterError: false
});
```

Alternatively you can set `restoreAfterError` in `formatoptions`:

```js
formatter: "actions", formatoptions: {restoreAfterError: false, keys: true, ...}
```

Comment: Hi oleg, I am getting the error from server side, How will I make sure the error goes into this block : onError: function (rowid, jqXHR, textStatus)

Comment: if possible let me know how to call on error function

Comment: @user2375298: `onError` is in general correct way, but you can set `errorfunc` callback in `$.jgrid.inlineEdit` too.

Comment: No my function will come into success as I m my http status will be success. But my validation are custom messages that is returning from server. So in that case how will I make the onError function is invoked

Comment: @user2375298: You need just set some error HTTP status code (>=400) in the HTTP response. Alternatively you can use `successfunc` instead of `errorfunc` but you need to return from `successfunc` the array `[false, "error message get from the server response"]`